# How to connect SAP ERP with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sap-erp, saprfc

I need to connect my VS code to the SAP system, because i need to develop a intern webshop. Unfortunately i can't find nothing for SAP ERP just fpr SAP HANA or S4/HANA i could find something. I find out that i need RFC and node.js for the connection but I could'n find more informations. Can anybody please help me

I haven't tried anything because i couldn't find the Informations i need. I just downloaded node.js

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.